# Java 8 Possible Double Lambda Expression

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda

I am creating a simulator, but for simplicity sake, it's a 'game'. Thus it has a render() and an update() function. I've been trying to practice lambda expressions during summer but I cannot seem to be able to wrap my head around doing a lambda expression of another lambda expression. I am probably saying this wrong, but what I am trying to do is start two threads, one *that **loops** rendering*, and another *that **loops** updating*. I can get this far:

```
void render() {
    //draw entities, etc.
}
void update() {
    //update player/enemies, etc.
}

public GameFrame() {
    /* init stuff */
    Thread updateThread = new Thread(this::update);
    Thread renderThread = new Thread(this::render);
}
```

This is not what I want because this only runs update and draw once, thus this is just two threads, one *that renders once*, and one *that updates once* (no looping). I want to create a function that does something along the lines of:

```
public void loop(Supplier< /*?*/ > arg) {
    long startTime;
    while(running) {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        supplier.get(arg) // <- not sure about this either
        try {
            long sleepTime = 1000/FPS - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
            if(sleepTime > 0)
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I would call the function like this?

```
loop(this::update);
```

I believe this would cause the supplied function to loop, thus I tried:

```
Thread updateThread = new Thread(this::loop(this::update));
```

Or even something like this:

```
new Thread(() -> loop(this::update)).start();
```

I know I can just make my render function while loop, and my update function while loop by just copying the 'void loop(Supplier arg)' code into each part, but I wanted to see if I could do it this way anyways.

I don't need an exact answer, I would just like some guidance to what I'm not thinking about/what I'm thinking about wrong. I haven't been able to make much progress by reading up on lambda expressions on oracle.

Comment: Your last idea is OK, but the loop() method should take a Runnable as argument, not a Supplier, since you want to execute a function that takes no argument, and returns nothing, and that's what a Runnable is. And it should thus call run() on that runnable, at each iteration.

Comment: First thing, why are you thinking about a "sleep loop" instead of using a Timer?

Comment: As an alternative to using bare metal threads, you could as well use ExecutorServices and keep submitting jobs into them. That wont help with lambdas, but it will making testing a whole lot easier (because you can replace a multi-threaded executor service with a "do-it-in-the-current-thread" executor easily.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I will look into timers. I didn't know what they were though.

Comment: @JBNizet Ah! Thank you that makes so much sense! I always looped inside the run() but never looped outside of it so I was not used to the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Thread` constructor takes [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) and this is what you want to execute repeatedly. Therefore you don't need `Supplier` as parameter type for `loop`, but `Runnable`.

```
public void loop(Runnable arg) {
    long startTime;
    while(running) {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        arg.run();
        try {
            long sleepTime = 1000/FPS - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
            if(sleepTime > 0)
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that is isn't possible to specify parameters with a method reference. This is invalid syntax:

```
this::loop(this::update)
```

The statement you want the thread to execute is:

```
loop(this::update);
```

so you need to use a lambda expression with this statement as body as parameter of the `Thread` constructor:

```
Thread updateThread = new Thread(() -> loop(this::update));
```

Note that a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) provides the kind of scheduling you're implementing here.

Comment: would you happen to know why Java does not allow: `this::loop(this::update)`? I noticed that if a function has a parameter, I must reference it like `() -> doFoo(arg)`. Why is this?

Comment: a) you need a target type for a method reference to work (for `this::loop` there isn't one) and b) even if you had a target type java doesn't support currying as a language feature, so you need to implement it differently.